# Unable to install db2 odbc drivers on windows

Tags: db2, odbc, driver

I am trying to download the IDM db2 odbc driver for windows according to  this instruction:
http://www.ryslander.com/how-to-install-and-configure-db2-odbc-driver/

From the ibm website, I download the below service pack:

```
IBM Data Server Client (Windows/x86-64 64 bit) V11.1.4 Fix Pack 4
```

But when I unzip it, I cannot see a 'bin' folder. I see a folder called CLIENT, and in there subfolders:db2,VSAI ,ibm_im & a setup.exe file.

What did I do wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded Data Server Client, then you should follow the [Installing IBM data server clients and drivers (Windows)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/t0007315.html) link.

It’s worth to read about [IBM data server client and driver types](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0022612.html?pos=2) as well.